# Get only one index from array

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

[image]

Guys, I want to get the array index. For example, if the index is 1 (segunda-feira), then displays the message within the clause `if(days.indexOf('segunda-feira'))`. However, it ends up displaying ALL `ifs`. How can I solve?

```
var data = new Date();
    var dias = new Array(
      'domingo', 'segunda-feira', 'terça-feira', 'quarta-feira', 'quinta-feira', 'sexta-feira', 'sábado'
    );
    if (dias.indexOf('segunda-feira')) {
      let m = await message.channel.send('*Um robô do Instituto apareceria na frente de seu receptor, afirmando:* - Hoje é ' + dias[1] + ', teremos aula de Combate!');
    } else {
      return false;
    }
    if (dias.indexOf('terça-feira')) {
      let m = await message.channel.send('*Um robô do Instituto apareceria na frente de seu receptor, afirmando:* - Hoje é ' + dias[2] + ', teremos aula de Estratégia!');
    } else {
      return false;
    }
    if (dias.indexOf('quarta-feira')) {
      let m = await message.channel.send('*Um robô do Instituto apareceria na frente de seu receptor, afirmando:* - Hoje é ' + dias[3] + ', teremos aula de Espionagem!');
    } else {
      return false;
    }
    if (dias.indexOf('quinta-feira')) {
      let m = await message.channel.send('*Um robô do Instituto apareceria na frente de seu receptor, afirmando:* - Hoje é ' + dias[4] + ', teremos aula de Defesa!');
    } else {
      return false;
    }
    if (dias.indexOf('sexta-feira')) {
      let m = await message.channel.send('*Um robô do Instituto apareceria na frente de seu receptor, afirmando:* - Hoje é ' + dias[5] + ', teremos aula de Resgate!');
    } else {
      return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current weekday using the method `getDay()`. 0 is Sunday and 6 is Saturday. You can also make an array of the course subjects as well and this should be all the code you need:

```
const hoje = new Date().getDay();
if(hoje == 0 || hoje == 6) {
    return;
}

const dias = ['domingo', 'segunda-feira', 'terça-feira', 'quarta-feira', 'quinta-feira', 'sexta-feira', 'sábado'];
const aulas = ['', 'Combate', 'Estratégia', 'Espionagem', 'Defesa', 'Resgate']
let m = await message.channel.send('*Um robô do Instituto apareceria na frente de seu receptor, afirmando:* - Hoje é ' + dias[hoje] + ', teremos aula de ' + aulas[hoje] + '!');
```

Comment: In the code, forgot to put plural in the part of `aula[hoje]`. Thanks there, yours was the only one that worked.

Comment: Fixed it. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Date.getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay).

```
const date = new Date();
const day = date.getDay();

if (day === 2) {
  // Tuesday
}
...
```